# how to set the scrollbar position to max? its not 1.0 as stated in the docs

Tags: qml, scrollbar

**UPDATE**

Fixed by calculating the needed position using the max content.x position and a 0.0-1.0 factor

```
Component.onCompleted:
{
    var maxContentX = content.width - frame.width
    var factor = 1.0 // 0, 0.5, 1.0
    var newPosition = (maxContentX*factor)/content.width
    hbar.position = newPosition
}
```

Qt-Docs: [ScrollBar QML Type](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-scrollbar.html)

[Position Property](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-scrollbar.html#position-prop)

> This property holds the position of the scroll bar, scaled to 0.0 -
> 1.0.

but the position never reaches 1.0 - because the position only holds 1 minus bar size

- i don't understand whats the sense is of scaling the position between 0 and 1 but then make it directly related to bar size
- are there any meaningful usages for position values above (1 minus bar-size)?
- is there a way to get the bar size?

[image]

any idea how to calculate the correct mid/max values for the position?
i want to build a timer that toggles between 0%, 50% and 100% position

Qt-Sample: [Non-attached Scroll Bars](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-scrollbar.html#non-attached-scroll-bars)

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15

Item
{
  height: 300
  width: 300
  
  Column
  {
    Text { text: "vbar.position: "+vbar.position }
    Text { text: "hbar.position: "+hbar.position }
  }

Rectangle {
    id: frame
    clip: true
    width: 160
    height: 160
    border.color: "black"
    anchors.centerIn: parent  

    Text {
        id: content
        text: "ABC"
        font.pixelSize: 160
        x: -hbar.position * width
        y: -vbar.position * height
    }

    ScrollBar {
        id: vbar
        hoverEnabled: true
        active: hovered || pressed
        orientation: Qt.Vertical
        size: frame.height / content.height
        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.right: parent.right
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
    }

    ScrollBar {
        id: hbar
        hoverEnabled: true
        active: hovered || pressed
        orientation: Qt.Horizontal
        size: frame.width / content.width
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.right: parent.right
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think I can answer the "why" part of your question. But to get the bar size, I believe you can use the Scrollbar's `contentItem` property. To get 0%, 50%, and 100%, you could probably do something like this (for a horizontal scrollbar):

```
// 0%
position: 0
// 50%
position: (width - contentItem.width) / width / 2
// 100%
position: (width - contentItem.width) / width
```

Comment: thanks for the tip, still not 100% correct - some pixels missing, but i've change the calculation to be independend of the contentItem.width by caculating the position for a certain content.x using "var neededPosition = (content.width - frame.width * factor) / content.width"